# .slideDown and .click(function() {$("#results").slideUp("slow");}); Clash

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have:

```
table2.assemble = function () {
  $("#results").slideDown("slow");
  $("#fullbody").click(function() {
    $("#results").slideUp("slow");
  });
}
```

embedded in a function that is called with an `onclick` of a search button that is in #fullbody

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  document.getElementById('sssearch').addEventListener('click', table2.assemble, false)
}, false);
```

The search results slide down fine...but slide up again instantly when I have not clicked a second time.

The div is:

```
<div id="results" style="display: none;">
</div>
```

Comment: You must be triggering a click somewhere else in your code. You need to provide all your code.

Comment: Have you tried calling the function via $('#sssearch').click() ?

Answer (score 0):

In the below code you are attaching a click handler to `fullbody` element inside a function which is called onclick of `sssearch` element. Every time you click `sssearch` the click handler is going to be attached. So there will be multiple `click` event handlers.

```
table2.assemble = function () {
  $("#results").slideDown("slow");
  $("#fullbody").click(function() {$("#results").slideUp("slow");});
}
```

Take it outside the function. I think the issue is here only.

```
$("#fullbody").click(function() {$("#results").slideUp("slow");});

table2.assemble = function () {
  $("#results").slideDown("slow");
}
```

Also to execute anything on page load you can use jQuery's `$(document).ready()` or `$()`.

```
$(function(){
   //Do your stuff here
});
```